# Kinetic energy on macro and micro situation

Tags: energy, kinematics, potential-energy

I just have this random question in my mind. If you drop something in deep space, and it falls due to a gravitational pull. As it's falling, its kinetic energy increases. I just wonder, is the average kinetic energy of atoms inside this object increasing?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is ***negative***.
The gravitational acceleration is the same for all the atoms. Thus, the internal structure of the body is *not affected*. Using the terminology in your question, *the average kinetic energy of atoms **inside this object*** doesn't change. This is the reason for which given a body left free in the gravitational field, we usually consider the gravitational force as acting on the center-of-mass (as if all the object's mass were confined to the center-of-mass).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The kinetic energy from translatoric motion of the object rises as a whole. Any small piece of it contributes with its' own fractional mass, since any small piece also achieves a net translatory motion. Each piece is a fraction of the whole object:

$$K_{trans}=½m_{total}v^2=\sum K_{trans,atom}$$

Comment: So wouldn't the atoms get so much energy that they break the bond between each other?

Comment: No, in general the relative motion of the atoms with respect to one another won't change.

Comment: The atom might gain enough energy to be able to break a bond. But as @Sofia says, even with all this energy, since they don't try to break free, then they don't. They don't try to start and movements relative to each other. If some external force helps them to redirect their energy, as when then object smashes into a rock after the long fall, then all the energy goes into smashing the object to pieces.

Comment: @Steeven the question is about an object submitted to the gravitational field. No additional forces are mentioned here. Then, no, the gravitational acceleration doesn't vary from atom to atom and **inside the object", as the user asks, the structure won't be changed.